# Existing implementations for NIST SP 800-56A Concatenation/Single-Step Key Derivation Function?

Tags: java, c++, security, cryptography, cryptoapi

Does anyone know of any existing implementations for NIST SP 800-56A Concatenation Key Derivation Function / CONCAT KDF (preferably in Java)?

The key derivation function is documented in section 5.8.1 of NIST's publication: Recommendation for Pair-Wise Key Establishment Schemes Using Discrete Logarithm Cryptography

Link here: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf

Microsoft's CNG has an implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but if you compare the function implemented by Microsoft, as compared to the parameters documented in NIST SP 800-56A, they do not tally, and the implementation by Microsoft is unusable. I have attempted to implement a sample program in C++ as well but I couldn't match the parameters.

Would anyone be able to attempt to implement it or know of any existing implementations?

I am looking for an implementation that is able to justify why it is accurate to the NIST specifications. I have seen a couple implementations out there and I feel that they are not accurate to the NIST specifications (missing parameters, invalid logic flow etc).

If you can implement it yourself, I am always glad to share my own source code for debate. Thanks! This would be a good contribution to the open source community!

EDIT:

Thanks to @Rasmus Faber, I can finally bring this question to a close, and hope to answer the same question that everyone else has as me.

Here's the code that I have edited based on @Rasmus Faber and my original codes:

**ConcatKeyDerivationFunction.java**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 * 
 * Implementation of Concatenation Key Derivation Function<br/>
 * http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56A/SP800-56A_Revision1_Mar08-2007.pdf
 *
 */

public class ConcatKeyDerivationFunction {

    private static final long MAX_HASH_INPUTLEN = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private static final long UNSIGNED_INT_MAX_VALUE = 4294967295L;
    private static MessageDigest md;

    public ConcatKeyDerivationFunction(String hashAlg) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlg);
    }

    public byte[] concatKDF(byte[] z, int keyDataLen, byte[] algorithmID, byte[] partyUInfo, byte[] partyVInfo, byte[] suppPubInfo, byte[] suppPrivInfo) {
        int hashLen = md.getDigestLength() * 8;

        if (keyDataLen % 8 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("keydatalen should be a multiple of 8");
        }

        if (keyDataLen > (long) hashLen * UNSIGNED_INT_MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("keydatalen is too large");
        }

        if (algorithmID == null || partyUInfo == null || partyVInfo == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Required parameter is null");
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            baos.write(algorithmID);
            baos.write(partyUInfo);
            baos.write(partyVInfo);
            if (suppPubInfo != null) {
                baos.write(suppPubInfo);
            }
            if (suppPrivInfo != null) {
                baos.write(suppPrivInfo);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        byte[] otherInfo = baos.toByteArray();
        return concatKDF(z, keyDataLen, otherInfo);
    }

    private byte[] concatKDF(byte[] z, int keyDataLen, byte[] otherInfo) {
        keyDataLen = keyDataLen / 8;
        byte[] key = new byte[keyDataLen];

        int hashLen = md.getDigestLength();
        int reps = keyDataLen / hashLen;

        if (reps > UNSIGNED_INT_MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key derivation failed");
        }

        int counter = 1;
        byte[] counterInBytes = intToFourBytes(counter);

        if ((counterInBytes.length + z.length + otherInfo.length) * 8 > MAX_HASH_INPUTLEN) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key derivation failed");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= reps; i++) {
            md.reset();
            md.update(intToFourBytes(i + 1));
            md.update(z);
            md.update(otherInfo);

            byte[] hash = md.digest();
            if (i < reps) {
                System.arraycopy(hash, 0, key, hashLen * i, hashLen);
            } else {
                System.arraycopy(hash, 0, key, hashLen * i, keyDataLen % hashLen);
            }
        }
        return key;
    }

    private byte[] intToFourBytes(int i) {
        byte[] res = new byte[4];
        res[0] = (byte) (i >>> 24);
        res[1] = (byte) ((i >>> 16) & 0xFF);
        res[2] = (byte) ((i >>> 8) & 0xFF);
        res[3] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
        return res;
    }
}
```

@Rasmus Faber: Thank you for your effort. I give you full credit for the above code. What I have done with the code above was to add in code to perform validation as required by the NIST specifications.

Also, I fixed a bug where the keyDataLen passed in was meant to specify the length in bits, but it was treated as the length in bytes. Hence, the key generated ended up being 8 times larger.

This was fixed by adding a line `keyDataLen = keyDataLen/8;` in the first line of the second method.

I thank everyone for their support and hope this piece of code will go a long way to the open source community!

Comment: Why don't you feel the CNG implementation is usable?

Comment: I was unable to match the parameters between the CNG implementation and the parameters defined in NIST SP 800-56A. For example, the CNG implementation does not even prompt for the hash algorithm to be used.

Comment: The Microsoft implementation has the hash-function hardcoded, yes (and I can't see *which* hash-function it is hard-coded to). Does that make it unusable to you? Are you looking for another implementation in order to verify your own?

Comment: I need an implementation where I can identify the hash-function. And yes, I need it to verify my own implementation. Also, the KDF is supposed to accept one secret as the input, but the Microsoft implementation asks for 2 secrets, which is confusing me as to how to use that implementation

Comment: The Microsoft implementation is used by performing the DH/ECDH secret agreement scheme and then deriving a key from the secret. You cannot directly provide the secret, which I can see makes it more difficult to use it to compare results.

Comment: Yes.. and in the NIST documentation, you provide the secret directly, which makes it difficult not just to compare results, but to use it as specified in the NIST documentation.

Comment: @LaiXinChu do you by any chance have an implementation of ConcatKDF for iOS?

Comment: Fwiw the acvp program through NIST now allows testing against the one step kdf https://usnistgov.github.io/ACVP/draft-hammett-acvp-kas-kdf-onestep.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty implementation:

```
    public byte[] concatKDF(String hashAlg, byte[] z, int keyDataLen, byte[] algorithmID, byte[] partyUInfo, byte[] partyVInfo, byte[] suppPubInfo, byte[] suppPrivInfo) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        baos.write(algorithmID);
        baos.write(partyUInfo);
        baos.write(partyVInfo);
        baos.write(suppPubInfo);
        baos.write(suppPrivInfo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    byte[] otherInfo = baos.toByteArray();
    return concatKDF(hashAlg, z, keyDataLen, otherInfo);
}

public byte[] concatKDF(String hashAlg, byte[] z, int keyDataLen, byte[] otherInfo) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    byte[] key = new byte[keyDataLen];
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlg);
    int hashLen = md.getDigestLength(); 
    int reps = keyDataLen / hashLen;
    for(int i=1;i<=reps;i++){
        md.reset();
        md.update(intToFourBytes(i));
        md.update(z);
        md.update(otherInfo);
        byte[] hash = md.digest();
        if(i<reps){
            System.arraycopy(hash, 0, key, hashLen*(i-1), hashLen);
        }else{
            if(keyDataLen % hashLen == 0){
                System.arraycopy(hash, 0, key, hashLen*(i-1), hashLen);
            }else{
                System.arraycopy(hash, 0, key, hashLen*(i-1), keyDataLen % hashLen);
            }
        }
    }
    return key;
}

public byte[] intToFourBytes(int i){
    byte[] res = new byte[4];
    res[0] = (byte) (i >>> 24);
    res[1] = (byte) ((i >>> 16) & 0xFF);
    res[2] = (byte) ((i >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    res[3] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!! I tested your code thoroughly, and managed to match your implementation to mine, till we got the same output! I really appreciate you taking the time to implement this. I have added validation to your code, and fixed a bug with the keyDataLen as described above. Please feel free to relook the code again and let me know if you spot anything!

Comment: Thanks once again! I will pass these codes to the community I am working with as we are currently in need of this ConcatKDF.

Comment: @LaiXinChu: Note that your modified implementation does not correctly handle key-lengths that are not a multiple of 8 bits. I think I would just fail if `keyDataLenInBits % 8 != 0`.

Comment: Yes good point. key-lengths should be a multiple of 8 bits for this implementation.

Comment: Just a warning: This implementation does ONLY work with key out length of the same size of hash out length. Otherwise it will return 0bytes for every odd block.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think you can find them other then test all on the list of `Validated Component Implementations` from http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/components/componentval.html.

There's only one supplier writing them in Java - Entrust http://www.entrust.com.

All of them are validated without the KDF :). The rest of work is up to you.

Comment: Sadly, all of them are validated without the KDF, and the KDF is exactly what I need! Hmm I will look into this. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The newer [NIST SP 800-56C rev1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Cr1.pdf), which moved the definition of KDFs for key agreement protocols from NIST SP 800-56A, defines 2 different KDFs:

### Single-Step KDF

Informally also referred to as "concat-kdf". Here is a standalone tested implementation of single-step kdf as described in NIST SP 800-56C rev1: https://github.com/patrickfav/singlestep-kdf

```
// a shared secret provided by your protocol
byte[] sharedSecret = ...
// a salt; if you don't have access to a salt, use salt-less SingleStepKdf.fromSha256() or similar
byte[] salt = ...
// other info to bind the key to the context, see the NIST spec for more detail
byte[] otherInfo = "macKey".getBytes();
byte[] keyMaterial = SingleStepKdf.fromHmacSha256().derive(sharedSecret, 32, salt, otherInfo);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyMaterial, "AES");
```

#### OtherInfo vs FixedInfo

Compared to older 800-56A versions, the `otherInfo` paramter was renamed to `fixedInfo`. It can be used to facilitate the propitiatory message format for the various key agreement schemes as described in the SP.

#### Test Vectors

I couldn't find any [official test vectors](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/where-can-i-find-official-test-vectors-for-nist-sp-800-56c-r1-single-step-kdf/64277#64277), so I released some here: https://github.com/patrickfav/singlestep-kdf/wiki/NIST-SP-800-56C-Rev1:-Non-Official-Test-Vectors

Here are some examples:

##### SHA-256

```
(z: afc4e154498d4770aa8365f6903dc83b, L: 16, fixedInfo: 662af20379b29d5ef813e655) = f0b80d6ae4c1e19e2105a37024e35dc6
(z: a3ce8d61d699ad150e196a7ab6736a63, L: 16, fixedInfo: ce5cd95a44ee83a8fb83f34c) = 5db3455a22b65edfcfde3da3e8d724cd
(z: a9723e56045f0847fdd9c1c78781c8b7, L: 16, fixedInfo: e69b6005b78f7d42d0a8ed2a) = ac3878b8cf357976f7fd8266923e1882
(z: a07a5e8df7ee1b2ce2a3d1348edfa8ab, L: 16, fixedInfo: e22a8ee34296dd39b56b31fb) = 70927d218b6d119268381e9930a4f256

(z: 3f892bd8b84dae64a782a35f6eaa8f00, L: 02, fixedInfo: ec3f1cd873d28858a58cc39e) = a7c0
(z: 3f892bd8b84dae64a782a35f6eaa8f00, L: 36, fixedInfo: ec3f1cd873d28858a58cc39e) = a7c0665298252531e0db37737a374651b368275f2048284d16a166c6d8a90a91a491c16f
(z: 3f892bd8b84dae64a782a35f6eaa8f00, L: 68, fixedInfo: ec3f1cd873d28858a58cc39e) = a7c0665298252531e0db37737a374651b368275f2048284d16a166c6d8a90a91a491c16f49641b9f516a03d9d6d0f4fe7b81ffdf1c816f40ecd74aed8eda2b8a3c714fa0

(z: 9ce5457e4a0eecc1c8709f7ef37a32e9, L: 16, fixedInfo: ) = 7d81e7d61acc06b90984ec4145469608
```

##### HMAC-SHA256

```
(z: 6ee6c00d70a6cd14bd5a4e8fcfec8386, L: 16, salt: 532f5131e0a2fecc722f87e5aa2062cb, fixedInfo: 861aa2886798231259bd0314) = 13479e9a91dd20fdd757d68ffe8869fb
(z: cb09b565de1ac27a50289b3704b93afd, L: 16, salt: d504c1c41a499481ce88695d18ae2e8f, fixedInfo: 5ed3768c2c7835943a789324) = f081c0255b0cae16edc6ce1d6c9d12bc
(z: 98f50345fd970639a1b7935f501e1d7c, L: 16, salt: 3691939461247e9f74382ae4ef629b17, fixedInfo: 6ddbdb1314663152c3ccc192) = 56f42183ed3e287298dbbecf143f51ac

(z: 02b40d33e3f685aeae677ac344eeaf77, L: 02, salt: 0ad52c9357c85e4781296a36ca72039c, fixedInfo: c67c389580128f18f6cf8592) = be32
(z: 02b40d33e3f685aeae677ac344eeaf77, L: 36, salt: 0ad52c9357c85e4781296a36ca72039c, fixedInfo: c67c389580128f18f6cf8592) = be32e7d306d891028be088f213f9f947c50420d9b5a12ca69818dd9995dedd8e6137c710
(z: 02b40d33e3f685aeae677ac344eeaf77, L: 68, salt: 0ad52c9357c85e4781296a36ca72039c, fixedInfo: c67c389580128f18f6cf8592) = be32e7d306d891028be088f213f9f947c50420d9b5a12ca69818dd9995dedd8e6137c7104d67f2ca90915dda0ab68af2f355b904f9eb0388b5b7fe193c9546d45849133d

(z: 2c2438b6321fed7a9eac200b91b3ac30, L: 56, salt: 6199187690823def2037e0632577c6b1, fixedInfo: ) = b402fda16e1c2719263be82158972c9080a7bafcbe0a3a6ede3504a3d5c8c0c0e00fe7e5f6bb3afdfa4d661b8fbe4bd7b950cfe0b2443bbd
(z: 0ffa4c40a822f6e3d86053aefe738eac, L: 64, salt: 6199187690823def2037e0632577c6b1, fixedInfo: ) = 0486d589aa71a603c09120fb76eeab3293eee2dc36a91b23eb954d6703ade8a7b660d920c5a6f7bf3898d0e81fbad3a680b74b33680e0cc6a16aa616d078b256
(z: a801d997ed539ae9aa05d17871eb7fab, L: 08, fixedInfo: 03697296e42a6fdbdb24b3ec) = 1a5efa3aca87c1f4
(z: e9624e112f9e90e7bf8a749cf37d920c, L: 16, fixedInfo: 03697296e42a6fdbdb24b3ec) = ee93ca3986cc43516ae4e29fd7a90ef1
```

### Two-Step KDF

The most prominent implementation of two-step kdf is probably [HKDF (RFC5869)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869). A tested and standalone Java implementation can be found here: https://github.com/patrickfav/hkdf

<sup>Disclaimer: I am the developer of both libraries.</sup>